# how to run docker compose using docker python sdk

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I would like to run docker-compose via python docker sdk. 
However I couldn't find any reference on how to achieve this using these reference [Python SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/examples/)? I could also use subprocess but I have some other difficulty while using that. see here [docker compose subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61973128/python-subprocess-for-docker-compose)

Comment: Docker Compose v1 (previously Fig) was actually written in Python. There is an SDK around somewhere for it.

Answer (score 4):

I created a package to make this easy: python-on-whales

Install with

```
pip install python-on-whales
```

Then you can do

```
from python_on_whales import docker
docker.compose.up()
docker.compose.stop()
# and all the other commands.
```

You can find the source for the package in my GitHub repository: https://gabrieldemarmiesse.github.io/python-on-whales/

Comment: If you recommend something you've made, you must disclose your affiliation, otherwise [it's considered spam](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). Simply saying "I wrote this package" is enough.

Comment: It appears you're affiliated with the GitHub repository linked here. When linking to or recommending something you're affiliated with, you *must disclose that affiliation in your post*. Without affiliation disclosure, it's considered spam. Please see: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212) and [the help center on self-promotion](/help/promotion). Disclosure must be explicit, but doesn't need to be formal. Disclosure can just be something like "my package", "my repository", "a repository I contribute to", etc. Please [edit] your post(s) to include disclosure.

Comment: I've gone ahead and edited in disclosure of affiliation for you. You're welcome to adjust it to something else, but some type of disclosure is required.

Comment: How do you use python_on_wheels to run docker compose in detached mode @Gabriel de Marmiesse?

Comment: Found it `docker.compose.up(detach=True)`

Answer (score 2):

I am working on the same issue and was looking for answers, but nothing so far. The best shot I can give it is to simplify that docker-compose logic. For example, you have a YAML file with a network and services - create them separately using Python Docker SDK and connect containers to a network.

It gets cumbersome, but eventually you can get things working that way from Python.